# How to get average value per object in a list with Dart

Tags: list, algorithm, dart, sorting

I have a chart that contains X and Y axis values stored in a list of object. This objects are represented by a class of this type:

```
class CartesianChartData {
  CartesianChartData(this.x, this.y);

  final String x;
  final double? y;
}
```

So, at the end lets say that I have a list of this type:

```
List<CartesianChartData> myList = [
      CartesianChartData('A', 25),
      CartesianChartData('A', 50),
      CartesianChartData('B', 25),
      CartesianChartData('B', 75),
      CartesianChartData('C', 100),
      CartesianChartData('D', 25),
      CartesianChartData('E', 0),
];
```

As you can see, I have duplicates of `A` and `B`. How can I calculate in the more efficient way the average value between this values and remove duplicates in the list?

I wanna have as result something like this:

```
List<CartesianChartData> myList = [
      CartesianChartData('A', 37.5),
      CartesianChartData('B', 50),
      CartesianChartData('C', 100),
      CartesianChartData('D', 25),
      CartesianChartData('E', 0),
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final myList = [
    CartesianChartData('A', 25),
    CartesianChartData('A', 50),
    CartesianChartData('B', 25),
    CartesianChartData('B', 75),
    CartesianChartData('C', 100),
    CartesianChartData('D', 25),
  ];

  // compute the average of the y values for each x value
  // this requires maintaining a sum and a count for each x value
  final sums = <String, double>{};
  final counts = <String, int>{};
  for (final item in myList) {
    sums.update(item.x, (value) => value + item.y!, ifAbsent: () => item.y!);
    counts.update(item.x, (value) => value + 1, ifAbsent: () => 1);
  }
  for (final entry in sums.entries) {
    sums[entry.key] = entry.value / counts[entry.key]!;
    print('${entry.key}: ${sums[entry.key]}');
  }
}

class CartesianChartData {
  CartesianChartData(this.x, this.y);

  final String x;
  final double? y;
}
```

produces

```
A: 37.5
B: 50.0
C: 100.0
D: 25.0
```

Comment: Thank you, really interesting algorithm. I'll surely learn a lot from this :)